# Problems trying to add a filter to a Grizzly+Jersey app

Tags: java, http, header, jersey, grizzly

I have this server initialization class:

```
package magic.app.main;

import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer;
import org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;

public class Main {
    public static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:4747/";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        /* SOME NON-RELEVANT CODE UP HERE */

        final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig();

        rc.packages("magic.app.resource");
        rc.register(magic.app.main.CorsSupportFilter.class);

        final HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI),rc);

        /* SOME NON-RELEVANT CODE DOWN HERE */
    }
}
```

And this filter class which I'm trying to register in the initialization class:

```
package magic.app.main;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder;

import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilter;

public class CorsSupportFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest req, ContainerResponse contResp) {

        ResponseBuilder resp = Response.fromResponse(contResp.getResponse());
        resp.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", Configuration.getHttpAllowOrigin())
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");

        String reqHead = req.getHeaderValue("Access-Control-Request-Headers");

        if(null != reqHead && !reqHead.equals(null)){
            resp.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", reqHead);
        }

        contResp.setResponse(resp.build());
        return contResp;
    }

}
```

When I run the app I get this piece of log:

```
WARNING: A provider magic.app.main.CorsSupportFilter registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider magic.app.main.CorsSupportFilter will be ignored.
```

I'm working with gradle and this is my app's Gradle build file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories{
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies{
    // IP2C
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

    // Jersey + Grizzly
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey:jersey-bom:2.4.1'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-grizzly2-http:2.4.1'

    // Jersey
    compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.17.1'
    compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.17.1'

    // JSON
    compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.13'
    compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'
    compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:1.9.13'
    compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'

    // Jersey + JSON
    compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:1.17.1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:2.3.0-rc1'

    // Postgres
    compile 'com.jolbox:bonecp:0.8.0.RELEASE'
    compile 'postgresql:postgresql:9.1-901-1.jdbc4'

    // Mail
    compile 'javax.mail:mail:1.5.0-b01'
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're mixing 2 versions of Jersey (1.x and 2.x) in your app. In your `Main` class you're using Jersey 2.x (package prefix is `org.glassfish.jersey`) and your `ContainerResponseFilter` is an implementation of Jersey 1.x proprietary API.

If you want to use Jersey 2.x the filter should implement [ContainerResponseFilter](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerResponseFilter.html) from JAX-RS 2.0.

In case you want to stick with Jersey 1.x you should change registration in your `Main` class (and also use grizzly container module from Jersey 1.x):

```
final ResourceConfig rc = new PackagesResourceConfig("magic.app.resource");
rc.getContainerResponseFilters().add(CorsSupportFilter.class);
```

Comment: ¡¡¡THANK YOU!!!. I KNEW it had something to do with my dependencies. But I did not knew Glassfish was providing Jersey v2 and Sun v1, ergo, my confusion. I was fighting with this since some time. After an analysis of Jersey v1 vs v2 I decided to go with v2. Some mild refactor later and I have now my API working again and as a standalone app. Again Thank you!.