# Spring boot how to handle throwable

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, throwable

I made a project like this [sample](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/). So the controllers are like this

```
package mypackagename.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class StoresRestController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String stores() {
        return ...
    }

}
```

I like to handle all throwables and make my customized unified response. The problem is I cannot find a guide or a sample to do this correctly.

First of all, I tried `ExceptionHandler`, with `Throwable`, but it didn't work, so I decided to move on. Then, the most close approach that I found is [this](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/error-handling-in-rest-api-with-jersey/), so I tried jersey, by adding something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27985714/2482947). But it's not working for all throwables. Also, it's ignoring my controllers, by complaining

```
o.g.jersey.internal.inject.Providers     : A provider mypackagename.controller.StoresRestController registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider mypackagename.controller.StoresRestController will be ignored.
```

I searched for this error and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19934761/2482947), which I'm not using `ContainerResponseFilter` in my project as I provided the sample above. So I'm clueless. The main problem is how to handle all throwables, but if you can give me some suggestions about how to solve `Providers` problem, I'll be so appreciated.

Comment: Thank you, I tried @ExceptionHandler as well. But as I understand they're not designed to handle all throwables.

Comment: Actually, as I explained I tried ExceptionHandler with throwable, but It didn't work, so I tried to other solutions like jersey.

Comment: There isn't any special exception that I want to catch. I want to have a unified response when my app throws any kind of exceptions. For example I don't want 'timestamp' in my response, which is included in the standard spring responses.

Comment: First, putting `try-catch` will make my controller ugly! The framework must catch them. This is the purpose of controllers, unless I want to handle everything by myself! Second, what about the exceptions in authorization process, they are not controllers! What about the exceptions of the framework itself? I want to handle all of them in one place and have a unified response.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By sping-boot exception I meant something like 'not found'. For example, I want to change this "{"timestamp":1489933640236,"status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/api/v1/store/245/sfadf"}" to this response "{"message":"No message available"}". Also `@ControllerAdvice` with `@ExceptionHandler` doesn't work with `Throwable.class`, which I test it again.

Answer (score 3):

In my project I use @ControllerAdvice to handle my exceptions. Here's an example. Hope this helps. Just make sure this class is on your component scan so it gets picked up.

```
@RestController
@ControllerAdvice
public class StoresExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleThrowable(final Throwable ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>("Unable to process request.", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30193013/2482947) post helped me to handle all `Throwable`s, except authentication exceptions. The important part was to use `@EnableWebMvc` and `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`. To handle authentication exceptions I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19788700/2482947) answer. Hope it's helping someone.

Answer (score 0):

as @carlos-cook said, you could use a `@ControllerAdvice` and, `ProblemDetail` defined in RFC 7807 which could look like:

```java
import org.springframework.http.ProblemDetail;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;

@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
  public ProblemDetail handleUnexpectedException(RuntimeException rte, WebRequest wr) {
        ProblemDetail pd = this.createProblemDetail(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, rte);
        pd.setType(URI.create("http://your-site.com/internal-server-error"));
        pd.setTitle("Internal server error");
        return pd;
    }

  @ExceptionHandler(YourCustomeException.class)
  public ProblemDetail handleUnexpectedException(YourCustomException rte, WebRequest wr) {
        ProblemDetail pd = this.createProblemDetail(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, rte);
        pd.setType(URI.create("http://your-site.com/custom-error-page"));
        pd.setTitle("Internal server error");
        return pd;
    }
}
```

Then in your controller you could simply throw `YourCustomException`

This controller advice will handle every exception and YourCustomException separately.